# Nginx redirect to base URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-redirect, nginx-location

I have the following address:

```
www.example.com/portal
```

And I want it to redirect it to:

```
www.example.com
```

How can I configure nginx to do this?

So far I have:

```
location /portal {
    return 301 $scheme:\\$server_name;
}
```

but it is not working. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try using a rewrite -

```
rewrite ^/portal    /    permanent;
```